# How to select the indexes of an 2 D array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a numpy 2D array where cartesian coordinates are stored as follows.

```
a = [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[4,6],[10,3], [2,10]]
```

How can I select all the array indexes to another array where (y cordinate >5)?

Thanks in Advance
Prasanna

Comment: for loop + if blocks maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
>>> a = np.array([[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[4,6],[10,3], [2,10]])
>>> a[:, 1] > 5 # Boolean mask
array([False, False, False,  True, False,  True])
>>> a[a[:, 1] > 5] # Filtered array
array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 2, 10]])
>>> np.where(a[:, 1] > 5)[0] # Array of indices
array([3, 5])
```

Comment: That `np.where()` should be replaced by `np.nonzero()`, eh.

Comment: It's you! And doesn't that give the same result?

Comment: Indeed it will, but the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) state: _When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses. The rest of this documentation covers only the case where all three arguments are provided._ I recognize your username, yet I somehow forgot where we last interacted ;p

Comment: Interesting—seems like a minor distinction at first, but I actually work a lot with `ndarray` subclasses so that is handy to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension quite easily for this purpose. I propose the following code which will iterate through the list "a", and produce a new list "b" with all y values greater than 5, this is seen in "if x[1]>5". Hope this helps!

```
  a = [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[4,6],[10,3], [2,10]]
  b = [x for x in a if x[1]>5]
```

now, b = [[4, 6], [2, 10]]

Comment: The answer posted by Seb is also good, and more numpy-esque. Though the same can be achieved with my solution by converting b to a numpy array. I would assume the np.where() function is indeed faster though.

Comment: op is asking for indexes ;) not entities